# ¿Crear un popup para que se abra después de clickear un link?

Tags: javascript, popup

gente que todo lo sabe.

Me gustaría saber como hacer un POPUP luego de darle click a un enlace, tal cual como muestra [esta página](https://planetadocumental.com/genius/#1)

Que tenga una 'X' para cerrar, con el título y poder modificar las dimensiones del video.

He buscado en google "como crear un popup en HTML"(es el único lenguaje que sé), pero la mayoría describen un popup que se abre automáticamente y ese no me sirve.

Encontré este código, lo que no sé es agregar lo que va en `<head> y </head>.` porque la entrada en Wordpress solo me permite agregar HTML, no deja modificar valores de la página entera.

```
    <script>
function abrir(url) {
open(url,'','top=300,left=300,width=300,height=300') ;
}
</script>

Esto va entre las etiquetas <head> y </head>.

Y agregar el siguiente código en todos los enlaces:

<a href="javascript:abrir('pagina.html')">Enlace</a>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO, te recomiendo leer [ask] y hacer el [tour] si todavía no lo has hecho. Te explico el por qué de los *dislikes*, aunque aquí sean votos negativos, no hay *likes* en SO. Aquí la mayoría trabajamos de esto, o somos grandes aficionados a esto, sea como sea, nuestro tiempo cuesta dinero y, cuando alguien viene a hacer una pregunta asumimos que es porque ***ya no le queda otra opción***. Dices que has hecho ***UNA*** búsqueda en google... eso es lo que hago yo cuando busco una receta de cocina. Cuando tengo un problema programando, abro *decenas* de tabs y busco de todas maneras...

Comment: ... y cuando llevo al menos una hora o dos buscando, ***intentando hacer cosas, PROBANDO***, es cuando vengo aquí a preguntar a otros. Porque StackOverflow debe ser un último recurso, porque lo más importante que puede aprender un programador, es a *aprender*, a buscarse la vida y dar con la solución correcta. Decía uno de mis profesores que los programadores solo somos gente que sabemos usar google mejor que el resto! Y razón no le faltaba... [aquí](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4884/cuanto-esfuerzo-se-espera-de-los-usuarios-de-stack-overflow) puedes leer más al respecto :)

Comment: Vale, compañero, gracias por la bienvenida y la observación, yo llevaba buscando algunas horas y no podía dar con la respuesta, intenté varios códigos que encontré pero no me funcionaron. Luego me di cuenta que necesitaba Javascript y aunque también lo intenté (pues hay cosas similares con el HTML) no me funcionó nada acerca de eso. Copié y revisé mucho el código fuente de la página de ejemplo y como no tenía mucho más tiempo un amigo me aconsejo esta web para que preguntara. pero tú tienes más experiencia en esto asi que tomaré tu recomendación. Seguiré buscando. Gracias de todas formas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen varias formas para hacer lo que dices, mi recomendación, "no reinventes la rueda" y utiliza una librería de JavaScript especializada para esto, por Ejemplo la librería [jquerymodal](https://jquerymodal.com/)

Solo agrega lo siguiente en el `<head></head>` de tu plantilla html

```
<!-- jQuery-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Modal -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Modal CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
```

Luego crea un div que contendrá el contenido de tu Ventana modal.

```
<div id="IdModal" class="modal">
  <p>Esto es un una ventana modal.</p>
  <a href="#" rel="modal:close">Cerrar</a>
</div
```

Luego crea un enlace y en el parámetro `href` linkealo al ID del contenido del modal

```
<a href="#IdModal" rel="modal:open">Abrir modal</a>
```

Ejemplo:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="IdModal" class="modal">
   <p>Esto es un una ventana modal.</p>
  <a href="#" rel="modal:close">Cerrar</a>
</div>

<p><a href="#IdModal" rel="modal:open">Abrir Modal</a></p>
```

Por ultimo, si lo que desea es que se active solo cuando se ingrese a tu sitio puedes agregar esto en el footer del sitio, antes de `</body>`

```
jQuery( '#IdModal' ).modal();
```

Si quieres que se active solo bajo un parámetro, por ejemplo, tusitio.com/?popup=abrir puedes usar esto.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if (window.location.search == "?popup=abrir") {
        jQuery( '#IdModal' ).modal();
    }
});
```

Espero esto te sirva, Suerte.